# SQL server : Inserting/updating missing data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table "Container" and "Control". These are existing tables and there is no foreign key relationship between the two. These are also very old tables so are not normalized. And I cannot change the structure now.

Below is the structure of the two tables.

Container table :

[image]

Control Table : 
[image]

The Name field in Control table contains CTableName+CPName from Container table.

I want to update the columnName field of Control table with the value of CID column of Container table. and also want to insert one more record (for ctable2 i.e the fourth row in final Control table below) in Control table.

The tablename and columnname columns have will always be have default values.

The final Control table should look like this:

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: Look into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Where is your new inserted row for ctable2?

Comment: "The Name field in Control table contains CTableName+CPName from Container table", this is a terrible idea, you really should have 2 columns instead

Comment: If this is a new table you are creating, I agree with Lamak - break out the pieces into their own columns. However, If this is something existing that has been thrown at you and you can't change without great effort. - Look into creating computed columns on the table to parse out the two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you want to apply this fix because you want normalize your table structure.

Try this:

First step:

In this way you'll UPDATE all Control rows with the value of Container table where the couple fields CTableName and CPName are the same of Name (excluding the rows of Container with the same couple fields)

```
UPDATE Control
SET ColumnValue = (
    SELECT c.CID
    FROM Container c
    WHERE c.CTableName + '+' + c.CPName = Control.Name
    AND NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 'PREVIOUS'
         FROM Container c2
         WHERE c.CTableName = c2.CTableName
         AND c.CPName = c2.CPName
         AND c.CID < c2.CID
    )
),
TableName = 'default', ColumnName = 'default'
WHERE ColumnValue IS NULL
```

Second step:

Adding elements don't present in Control table

```
INSERT INTO Control (field list)
SELECT field list
FROM Container co
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'in_control'
    FROM Control ct
    WHERE co.CID = ct.ColumnValue
)
```

After these two steps you can drop column Name in Control table

Comment: i dont want to normalize the table. I just want to insert the data

Comment: @sid: The last word is your ;) But two queries are ok?

Answer (score -2):

I am an Oracle plsql programmer and worked with Sql-server as well.

First you should describe the relationship between the 2 tables, in the end i could figger it out but it's better you explain it yourself.
To update a table with information from another table you should ask yourself:
- when should the update take place?
- what are the conditions to start the update?
- how should the update be done?

In Oracle there is a database object called a trigger. It's quite a handy object and probably just what you need. I believe that sql-server has it too.

Pls fee free to ask any questions but do read the sql-server appropriate manual as well.

Good luck, Edward.